# nginx rewrite rules failing - causing 503 errors

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx 2 virtual hosts on Nginx 1.4.1 and it doesn't work. when I comment out the first virtual host it works fine. Below gives me a 503 error.

Any ideas what I should try?

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name website.co;
  rewrite ^(.*) http://www.website.co$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name www.website.co;
  index index.php;
  root /var/www/html/website.co;
  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/website.co.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  }
```

}

thankyou

Comment: Is this `/tmp/website.co.sock` the path of your sock file ?

Comment: also please provide us with the error line from the error log file `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a real answer yet, but a rewrite for your redirect block ( until you provide more info on the error log )

**Also please verify that the php sock file is actually located at** `/tmp/website.co.sock`

change this

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name website.co;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.website.co$1 permanent;
}
```

to this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.co;
    return 301 $scheme://www.website.co$request_uri;
}
```

It's more efficent because it doesn't need a rewrite engine.